# How to control the mouse pointer via my keyboard?

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse

How to control(or simulate) my mouse pointer movements using keyboard shortcuts (on Ubuntu 11.10).

Comment: This might be helpful: askubuntu.com/questions/17653/is-there-an-xpadder-equivalent

Comment: All programs in this post is about using joysticks movements instead of mouse, but not controlling mouse via keyboard.

Comment: you can map the keyboards keys too...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you go to "System Setting" -> "Universal Access" -> "Pointing and Clicking" and activate "Mouse Keys" you can use the numpad keys to move the mouse pointer.

Comment: Thanks working well, but how to simulate the mouse wheel and how to activate mouse keys without going to "System Setting" -> "Universal Access" -> "Pointing and Clicking" and activate "Mouse Keys", i mean with a keyboard shortcut