# How do I pair a Nintendo Joycon?

Tags: bluetooth, 16.10

Was thinking of using a joycon as a presenter's clicker. A quick test on my Android phone shows it paired just fine via Bluetooth, though the input is a bit slow and laggy.

However, in 16.10 the Device Search doesn't seem to discover the joycon in sync mode. I've paired bluetooth headphones to this computer successfully, so I don't think it's the hardware. Are there settings or libraries I need to tweak to fix this?

Comment: I remember trying to connect a wiimote and it did not connect in its discover mode. Inside the wiimote was a small button and that had to be used for the connection, rather than the normal way of connecting to a wii. Perhaps the Joycon has something like that? I don't have one to check.

Comment: @MarkKirby yes, the joycon has a sync button I have to press. Recall that I'm able to pair it with an Android phone, so it's unlikely a user error =)

Answer (score 0):

Just tried a laptop I have at home, and it worked. Keybuttons aren't recognized, but that might be a bluetooth joystick button mapping thing on a per app basis I need to investigate more.

Not sure why it didn't work on the desktop though!

Answer (score 0):

On PopOS 21.10 (Ubuntu derivative), I got this working by following [the advice in this answer:](https://askubuntu.com/a/866336/271734):

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-joystick
```

and then rebooting. Both JoyCon joysticks work for controlling the mouse (and moving them together makes it move faster). The right JoyCon can use `B` for left click and `X` for right click.